# Creating a table with arithmetic overflow error

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'am making a table with the data type of char, decimal and date in its attributes. I have received a result of some Arithmetic overflow error. Wonder if you could help me learn create this table.THANKS :D

```
Create table JOB (JOB_CODE char (3), JOB_DESCRIPTION char(25), JOB_CHG_HOUR decimal (4,2), JOB_LAST_UPDATE date)

Insert into JOB (JOB_CODE, JOB_DESCRIPTION, JOB_CHG_HOUR , JOB_LAST_UPDATE )
Values (500, 'Progammer', 35.75, '26-Nov-09'),
(501, 'Systems Analyst', 96.75, '20-Nov-09'),
(502, 'Database Designer', 125.00, '24-Mar-10'),
(503, 'Electrical Engineer', 84.50, '20-Nov-09'),
(504, 'Mechanical Engineer', 67.90, '20-Nov-09'),
(505, 'Civil Engineer', 55.78, '20-Nov-09'),
(506, 'Clerical Support', 26.87, '20-Nov-09'),
(507, 'DSS Analyst', 45.95, '20-Nov-09'),
(508, 'Application Designer', 48.10, '24-Mar-10'),
(509, 'Bio Technician', 34.55, '20-Nov-09'),
(510, 'General Support', 18.36, '20-Nov-09')
```

this is the exact message result:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your field `JOB_CHG_HOUR` can only hold numbers of 4 digits, with two decimals, so up to 99,99. You are trying to insert a row which contains 125,00 as a `JOB_CHG_HOUR` value. That's why you are overflowing (exceeding the capacity) of that field. Consider changing your create statement to:

```
CREATE TABLE JOB
(
    JOB_CODE CHAR(3), 
    JOB_DESCRIPTION CHAR(25), 
    JOB_CHG_HOUR DECIMAL(5,2), --will now hold up to 999,99
    JOB_LAST_UPDATE DATE
);
```

Also, according to the table creation statement you have, the field `JOB_CODE` is of type `CHAR(3)`, so you need quotes in your insert statements.

```
INSERT INTO JOB (JOB_CODE, JOB_DESCRIPTION, JOB_CHG_HOUR , JOB_LAST_UPDATE)
VALUES('500', 'Programmer', 35.75, '26-Nov-09');
```

Don't forget the semicolon `;` at the end of your statement!

Comment: No problem! @RYREN

Answer (score 0):

`JOB_CHG_HOUR` is `decimal (4,2)`

From the documentation:

> **s (scale)**
>
> The number of decimal digits that will be stored to the right of the decimal point. This number is subtracted from p to determine the maximum number of digits to the left of the decimal point.

Therefore you have 2 digit max left to the point and hance it will not accept 125.00

Comment: i see now, that's why it tells me that I'am exceeding, anyway thanks sir!